# Firebase auth and Apple Sign-in with multi-tenancy

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm using multi-tenancy in my auth and everything is OK with Facebook and Google.

But with Apple Sign-in this don't work.

In firebase console I can to configure Apple witch Sign-in method like the screenshot.

[image]

But my request return "The identity provider configuration is not found" when I add tenancy configuration in auth.

```
firebase.auth().tenantId = <MY_TENANT>
```

I noticed that Identity Provider cofiguration in Google Cloud Console dont have an Apple provider:

[image]

Any idea for this?

Comment: Sign in with Apple is not yet supported with multi-tenancy in Identity Platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have a bug in firebase auth: Available in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3611